# PowerShell ConvertTo-HTML list with only value

Tags: html, list, powershell

There's a custom object I created with a lot of key value pairs. Now I'm trying to create an HTML list of only the value and no name (header).

Example:

```
Get-ADnewUsers | Select-Object 'name' | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As List
<table>
<tr><td>*:</td><td>User1</td></tr>
<tr><td><hr></td></tr>
<tr><td>*:</td><td>User2</td></tr>
<tr><td><hr></td></tr>
<tr><td>*:</td><td>User3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Output:

```
*: User1
*: User2
*: User3
```

How can I get rid of the name column? Thank you for your help.

```
Get-ADnewUsers | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As List -Property 'Display name'
```

Output:

```
name: User1
name: User2
name: User3
```

But I would like it to generate only this:

```
User1
User2
User3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation:

> The LIST value generates a two-column HTML table for each object that resembles the Windows PowerShell list format. The first column displays the property name; the second column displays the property value.

So it seems that behavior can't be modified with a different syntax.

What you could do, though, is strip the `<td>name:</td>` from each line of the result:

```
Get-ADnewUsers | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As List -Property 'name' | % { $_ -replace '<td>name:</td>', '' }
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, I didn't think about that as I was so focused on having `ConvertTo-Html` do the job for me. Thanks man :)